# How to check if an li contains an element with a specific classname in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure, and I want to find out if `.curent-menu-item` has a child with a class of `.sub-menu`

```
<li class="curent-menu-item">
   <a>text</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>text</li>
```

Comment: .find would be a good start

Comment: .hasClass() will also work

Comment: Do you want to do something with the `li` if it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( $('.curent-menu-item .sub-menu').length )
if ( $('.curent-menu-item').has('.sub-menu').length )
if ( $('.curent-menu-item').find('.sub-menu').length )
if ( $('.curent-menu-item').children('.sub-menu').length )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hasChild = $('.curent-menu-item').find('.sub-menu').length > 0 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `if($('ul.sub-menu').children('ul').hasClass('sub-menu'))`

Answer (score 0):

`$('li ul').hasClass('sub-menu')` `\\ returns true if has  sub-menu`